# How to set the cursor in a console application to the end?

Tags: c#, console-application

Lets say i have a console application with these commands:

```
Console.WriteLine("Line1");
Console.WriteLine("Line2");
Console.WriteLine("Line3");
Console.SetCursorPosition(1,0);
Console.Write("\b");
```

So that the result will look like this:

```
ine1
Line2
Line3
```

How can i set the cursor Position to the end of everything, so that the cursor Position is after `Line3`?

I can't set it to something like `Cursor.SetCursorPosition(0,3)` because the length of all lines is not always the same.

Comment: Use Console.CursorLeft/Top before SetCursorPosition, store them in two variables.  Then you can use SetCursorPosition again to put it back where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to detect, based on the text of the console, where your cursor was before you started changing it, it's easier to just store the position of the cursor (by reading the property values and storing them in variables) before changing it, so that you know where to go back to.